# "around" = "on the subject of"

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

In recent months I have on a number of occasions heard people use the word "around" when they mean "on the subject of."

E.g. "I can answer your questions around your investments."

I don't recall having heard this before 2021, but suddenly I've heard it repeatedly.

Has this been noted by people who pay attention to such things? Is it brand-new or have I been isolated?

Comment: This form of usage probably has become more common in recent years—but it has been in use for a long time. I suspect that in the instance you mention—"questions around X"—the wording arose out of the similar-sounding form "questions surrounding X." At any rate, I find examples such as "Charles Thomas, professor and director of the University of Florida's criminal justice program, says police and legal resources have been used inappropriately in trying to **answer the questions around** Kennedy's death" (from May 21, 1984) dating back decades.

Comment: This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=questions+around&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) of British usage 1900-2019 seems to show a recent surge, and if it were possible to exclude all the false positives - *asking questions around the table/class/world/clock*, *questions around which/around 11.00* and others - it might be even more dramatic. I agree with Sven Yargs's suspicions about "questions surrounding X". FWIW I first heard it among primary school teachers in the late 1990's. I find it annoyingly vague.

Comment: *I have on a number of occasions heard people use the word "around" when they mean "on the subject of."* I think it is somewhat broader and means more "in the general area of", thus inviting questions that do not bear directly on the subject.

Comment: This sounds like City talk or Wall Street. Jargony. Not regular. These finance people always seem to come up with expressions that make most of us shudder.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Wiktionary definition *centered upon* best covers your example:

> I can answer your questions around your investments.

In fact, you might interpret it as broader than "on the subject of" in many cases, as Greybeard states in a comment. Note the 1897 date of the OED's first citation for this sense, in line with the Ngram in Old Brixtonian's comment.

**around** (prep.)

> *(Of abstract things)* **Centred upon**; surrounding.
>
> *There has been a lot of controversy around the handling of personal information.*[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/around)

> **11.** In reference or relation to; concerning, about.
>
> **1897**   *Punch* 29 May 263/3   Essence of Parliament... Useful, but not precisely alluring, debate around Employers' Liability Bill.
>
> **2013**   Church Times 20 Sept. 34/4   Her biblical reflections..are thought provoking, and will..act as a stimulus to further biblical
> enquiry around the themes of justice and hospitality. (OED)

---

> Grant-making foundations have their own special rules **around
> investments**. [W. Ginn; *Valuing Nature: A Handbook for Impact
> Investing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Valuing_Nature/_s3XDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Grant-making%20foundations%20have%20their%20own%20special%20rules%20around%20investments&pg=PA166&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> Each page provided an opportunity for the more for the more in-depth
> research and information that the Working Group had reviewed **around
> each topic** to be profiled and made available to any group or coalition
> in the community wanting to champion action **around that topic.** [R.
> Phillips and C. Wong (eds.); *Handbook of Community Well-Being Research*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Handbook_of_Community_Well_Being_Researc/VyO1DQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22around%20that%20topic%22&pg=PA153&printsec=frontcover)
> (2016)

> While you are searching for literature **around your question**,
> consider also how you think you may want to go about answering that
> question (for example, through a survey, observation, or interview).
> [Bruno Boynton; *Crossfire in Professional Education*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Research_Companion/pCQlDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22around%20your%20question%22&pg=PA32&printsec=frontcover) (2014)